# How to implement SSL/htaccess into a simple non-cms website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, security, ssl-certificate

I've coded a website myself (html, css, a bit of jquery/javascript and php, with a database connection). It's in essence just a simple portfolio with text, a carousel of photos/designs/videos and some pdf files. So, no users are involved except a simple login for myself to upload additional photos or designs. These photos, designs and videos are saved in a simple database.

Whenever I go to my website in e.g. a safari browser, safari let's me know that the website is 'not safe' because I don't have a SSL certificate or .htaccess file. (So, my website is http://example.com and not https://example.com). However, it works perfectly regardless of the 'not safe' notification in the browser bar.

I've contacted the hosting company and they told me to create a .htaccess file and place it in the public_html folder.

This is the content of that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, when I add this to my public_html folder, my website simply doesn't work. When I go to example.com it correctly redirects to https://example.com, but I get this notification:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

When I delete the .htaccess file, it works again (but is unsafe according to my browser).

The hosting company responded with: "we are not website builders so we can't help you with this", so I'm at a loss on how to fix this. Hence this post.

How do I fix this, without a cms to depend on?

Comment: _We_ did not build your website either, so we don’t know anything about how it works internally either. But if you get a 404 when just trying to access the root at `https://example.com/` already, whereas the HTTP version works - then my first guess would be, that this gets “routed” into different directories to begin with. What happens when you remove this .htaccess again, and then try to access `https://example.com/` directly in your browser? If that does not work either, then this is a problem with your hosting setup in general, and has nothing to do with these rewrites in particular.

Comment: When I remove it it still redirects to https. When I remove it + clear my history/caches, then it works again. So, in summary: my website works fine without the .htaccess file.

I know you won't know how my website works internally, but I figured I was missing some (to you) obvious code somewhere when I add in the .htaccess file: code which is necessary when you don't use a CMS but which I am not aware of.

Comment: _“then it works again”_ - what _exactly_ “works again” then - accessing it via HTTP, or HTTPS?

Comment: Accessing it via HTTP://example.com. So the non-secure one. When I don't add the .htaccess file to my server and try to acces https://example.com, it gives the same notification as when I do add the .htaccess file and try to access https://example.com.

Comment: See, so then it has nothing whatsoever to do with your attempt to rewrite to HTTPS, but your site is not properly reachable via HTTPS in the first place. If your hoster was supposed to configure SSL for your, then you should ask them what’s up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not on the code, it depend on apache configuration, if you have access to the server ssh, look this tool : https://certbot.eff.org/. if you're not, the hosting compagny have to resolve you're problem.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the configuration. The 'use a symbolic link' option wasn't enabled, which caused the issue.